# EnumMap Initialization from a HashMap

Tags: java, junit

I've looked to find that initializing a java EnumMap is possible with value of another HashMap but this is with testing.  I'm not in need of using an efficient double bracket or anything like that I just need to create the map from a given map.

```
public EnumMap<ITEMS, Map<String, Double>> getPromotionItems(String state, Map<String, Double> prices) {
    EnumMap<ITEMS, Map<String, Double>> promoItems = new EnumMap<>(ITEMS.class);
    Iterator iterator = prices.entrySet().iterator();
    Iterator keys = prices.keySet().iterator();

    HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        map.put(iterator.next(),keys.next());
    }
    promoItems.put(ITEMS.valueOf(state),map);
    return promoItems;
}
```

I'm writing in Junit and this says that my iterators are wrong somehow

`java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.EnumMap<{ORIGINAL={ProductC=3.0, ProductA=1.0, ProductB=2.0}}> but was: java.util.EnumMap<{ORIGINAL={ProductC=3.0, ProductA=1.0, ProductB=2.0}}>`

**SOLUTION**
I needed to use only one enumMap in my class and unit test calling the method using the test class enumMap.

This was in my test class: TestClassForItems.java
    public enum ITEMS {
        ONPROMO, ORIGINAL, OFFPROMO
    }

```
@Test
public void onRedLinePromotionListOriginalPriceTest() {
    testPromoState = "ORIGINAL";

    testPrices.put("Product_A", 1.00);
    testPrices.put("Product_B", 2.00);
    testPrices.put("Product_C", 3.00);
    expectedPrices = testPrices;
    expectedGoodsMap.put(TestClassForItems.ITEMS.ORIGINAL, testPrices);

    assertSame(expectedGoodsMap, TestClass.getPromotionItems(TestClassForItems.ITEMS.ORIGINAL,testPrices));
}
```

Returning the same String result but different object usage due to instantiating from the main for all of the necessary attributes to run my Junit test.

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: @shmosel made an edit trying compiling now and see what you think.

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed, but `iterator`, `keys` and `map` are all using raw types.

Comment: The semantics here are very unclear; you apparently don't want the available `EnumMap` copy constructor, but this appears to be picking final values at random in the case of key collisions in the submap.

Comment: There's a definte simpilistic approach to this (which is below and giving the same Error) but the above symantics are simply to populate the map and return it with the values passed in. @chrylis

Comment: And don't you should post your testing code here?

Answer (score 2):

A short solution:

```
public EnumMap<ITEMS, Map<String, Double>> getPromotionItems(String state, Map<String, Double> prices) {
    EnumMap<ITEMS, Map<String, Double>> promoItems = new EnumMap<>(ITEMS.class);
    promoItems.put(ITEMS.valueOf(state), new HashMap<>(prices));
    return promoItems;
}
```

You have confused the data types. You are using a Entry as a String. If you define the data type with the right generic value, you'll get a compile error:

```
public EnumMap<ITEMS, Map<String, Double>> getPromotionItems(String state, Map<String, Double> prices) {
    EnumMap<ITEMS, Map<String, Double>> promoItems = new EnumMap<>(ITEMS.class);
    Iterator<Entry<String, Double>> iterator = prices.entrySet().iterator();
    Iterator<String> keys = prices.keySet().iterator();

    HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        map.put(iterator.next(), keys.next());
    }
    promoItems.put(ITEMS.valueOf(state), map);
    return promoItems;
}
```

Comment: The edit still gives what I was getting.  Trying running it again. @David Perez Cabrera

Comment: Perez Cabrera The solution was what I started with but the issue is JUnit.  Those results shouldnt be showing an AssertionError.

Comment: Perez Cabrera I added the test along with the enum map that I'm working with so you can see what the Assertion is.  I've also tried it with 'AssertSame' and 'AssertTrue' using the .equals() getting the same result.

Comment: @April_Nara You must change assertSame to assertEquals as Bohemian said.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
assertSame
```

To:

```
assertEquals
```

`assertSame()` is the same as `==`, whereas `assertEquals()` does an `equals()` compare.

Comment: the equals seems to be the object comparison I'm looking for and as you can see the results above were exactly the same for both.  How are expected and actual results the same with an AssertionError?